# Is there a -w equivalent for isql when already connected?

Tags: sybase, isql

The default output (text) width in sybase isql is 80. It can be changed with the `-w` flag when isql is started on a command line:

```
isql -w 200 -S... -U... -P...
```

Now, I am wondering if there is a possibility to change the text width when I am already connected. I would have expected something like

```
1> set columnwidth 200
2> go
```

or something similar. Yet, in the documentation I am unable to find something in this direction. So, does that mean that this is impossible or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to change dynamically this parameter. 
I have found this article:

[How do I pipe the output of one isql to another](http://www.isug.com/Sybase_FAQ/ASE/section4.html).

There, you can look at the other utilities to use in this scenario (sqsh, for example).
Luck.